# Unicode support for android - How to identify fontavailable on particular device

Tags: android, unicode, android-2.2-froyo

We looked at various threads on stackoverflow, so do understand limitation of some fonts on lower android version.

Is there way to identify whether particular device has unicode font available ( e.g. Hindi, Chinese, etc )?

If we get to know which fonts are available then we will display unicode support only on those phone..

So what we want to achieve is method something like isUnicodeAvailable(fontname/FontType)

Settings page

```
Some Method (){

    if ( **isUnicodeAvailable(FontName)** ) {
           //Show text with unicode
    }else{
          //Show normal text
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “unicode font”? A Unicode-encoded font? I’m pretty sure all fonts on Androids are. A font that covers all of Unicode? There can be no such font, as Unicode has more (allocated) characters that fit in one font.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - I don't think android lower <4.2 supports all fonts..

Comment: Who said it would? (Whatever support to all fonts might mean.) Please clarify the question as suggested (by editing your question).

Comment: is there method available which will tell me which fonty type is supported on device?